# Least squares fitting for a non linear function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, chi-squared

I have some data:

```
xdata = [ 298.134  299.024  299.912  300.808  301.732  302.635  303.603  304.476
  305.35   306.223  307.18   308.091  308.938  309.902  310.792  311.663
  312.566  313.412  314.284  315.252  316.126  317.002  317.913  318.81
  319.669  320.626  321.523  322.417  323.281  324.245]


 ydata = [-9.48357662093877, -9.5792580093353656, -9.7144993201777972, -9.8715380997132574, -10.027248712603699, -10.177417977875871, -10.352374953002723, -10.517136866838991, -10.715774762340427, -10.913431451028842, -11.123817784132052, -11.345932175131191, -11.567233115011238, -11.775872934970939, -11.992878335292444, -12.21474839185972, -12.382545106102548, -12.45951145012326, -12.697558713087753, -12.870960915450144, -13.122795212623657, -13.096364398875277, -13.3741438677707, -13.323032960465998, -13.436772613480292, -13.561709556757362, -14.198404910172693, -13.896250284916482, -13.535947150817048, -14.727538560421378]
```

I would like to do a least squares fitting on this data.  The function that I would like to test is f(a,b,x) = -a*sqrt(b/x - 1).  I want to find a good value for the constants a and b, and I would like to get a chi squared value for the fit.  How would I do this?

Comment: Reading [scipy.optimize documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) might help

Comment: Thank you.  This specific example http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#example-of-solving-a-fitting-problem will help me obtain values for the parameters a and b, but how would I obtain a chi squared value for the fit to the data?

Comment: Also, does the least_squares function come with Anaconda?  Because from scipy.optimize import least_squares gives an import error.